# PHP Bug in Syntax unexpected /

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error exception:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFgaZ.png

[image: Laravel Error Exception]

It just states that I got a syntax error on line 51:

> syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')'

But I seriously can't detect, why I should have a syntax error. To make things worse, on my locel environment, I am not getting any errors, just on the server.

Pretty weird, here is the part of my code:

```
   // Get the percentual difference of 


   if (! empty($avgp[$day][$i] / max($avg[$day][$i],1))) {
       $trend[$day][$i]                = round($avgp[$day][$i] / max($avg[$day][$i],1) -1 , 4) * 100;
   } else {
       $trend[$day][$i]                = 0;
   }
```

http://pastebin.com/rPne5JtY

Thanks in advance.

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use () before division operator. I.e. put both variable inside () before division

SO
for example.

```
($avg[i]) /(max($avg[i]));
```

Comment: Thx a lot. 

I solved it by the way in a different way. I upgraded the PHP-Version from 5.4 to 5.5 on the live server. That closed the deal, weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
$trend[$day][$i] = round( ( $avgp[$day][$i] ) / max( $avg[$day][$i],1 ) -1 , 4 ) * 100;
```

try that

Comment: Hi Caweren, you should add an explanation to the code you provide in an answer, that will help the one who asked the question more.